# Is an "algebraic" subspace of an associated analytic space a subvariety of the original variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over $\mathbb C$, and $X_h$ its associated analytic space. If there is a variety $Y$ that $Y_h$ is a open subset of $X_h$, would $Y$ or some subvariety of $Y$ be a subvariety of $X$? I don't know if GAGA would be helpful, since $Y_h$ is not really open in the projective space. The Euclidean topology is finer than Zariski topology, so this might be to much to hope for, but I guess $Y$ should tell us sth about the local property of $X$.